# Splitting a zoomed terminal in Terminator?

Tags: linux, zoom, terminator

```
$ apt-cache show terminator
Package: terminator
Version: 0.97-4
```

A terminal window in terminator can be split horizontally or vertically, however if you zoom a terminal, it has to be restored before it's splittable again. Is it possible to split a zoomed window, and when the original zoomed window is restored, the splits created in the zoomed state shrinks accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Not soure if you can change that, but you probably can create a shortcut/alias in the config file to spit window and move the new window to the top with a combination of `Ctrl+Shift+O` and `Alt+Up`